# JSON vs classic schema design

Tags: sql, database, json, schema

My partner and I are working for a college level final project, and we've now come to the point where we want to design our database. right now, we have a c# JSON serializer and deserializer, and plan to store that into our database

so as i was designing our class schema, my partner mentioned why not just have a table with all the JSON strings? I am not sure what to do because intuitively, it does not seem right to have a few fields and then a string. we would select from that table and then deserilize all of the strings and you would get the information.

however, the more i thought about it, I'm not sure if theres much of a difference since whenever we need to edit, we would need to edit the JSON string anyways and restore it into the database. I think that this design would make the database just a data-dump, but our project is not large scale enough to need a full out design.

I know my problem is not very well described, but any thoughts on this? would you just store the JSON string? or would you have a classic schema? i think it really depends

Comment: You're really asking relational versus NoSQL.  I'd look into Mongo and others quickly to see if a document based solution could work for you.

Comment: A negative to storing the json string in a column is that if you ever need to query for some subset of that json, it will be very difficult to do that.